# RegExp for : number(,number){n}

Tags: mysql, regex

I would like to have a regular expression for:

```
number(,number){n}

which could match :
   1
or 1,1
or 1,1,1
```

where `1` is any integer number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether `\d` works at mysql or not. You can use this one:

```
^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$
```

If you need to match any fix length instead of `*`, then you can use `{n}` as well.

```
^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+){2}$
```

For both cases, remove the `+` sign if you need to match only one digit instead of a series of digits.

Answer (score 4):

The following regex should suit your needs:

```
^[[:digit:]]+(?:\,[[:digit:]]+)*$
```

If you don't want to catch more than one number at a time (e.g.: `123,123`), then change it to* `^[[:digit:]](?:\,[[:digit:]])*$`